# How to split a name separated by comma(even occurrence) in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select EL_VALUES_FIELD1, regexp_substr(f_person_name_multiple(EL_VALUES_FIELD2,0), '[^,  ]+', 1, level)
from DATA_FORM_VALUES_1322308
connect BY  regexp_substr(f_person_name_multiple(EL_VALUES_FIELD2,0),'[^,  ]+', 1, level) is not null
```

Input String is as follows:

```
Kanodia, Gaurav,Punani, Rohit,Singhal, Bhavya
```

Expect Outcome is as follows

```
Kanodia, Gaurav
Punani, Rohit
Singhal, Bhavya
```

Answer (score 3):

If input string **always** looks like the one you showed us, then

- replace the second comma with something else (e.g. `#`)
- split the input string on `#` (instead of `,`)
- `level` will, in that case, always be `<= 2`

---

```
SQL> with test (col) as (select 'Kanodia, Gaurav,Punani, Rohit' from dual)
  2  select regexp_substr(regexp_replace(col, ',', '#', 1, 2), '[^#]+', 1, level) res
  3  from test
  4  connect by level <= 2;

RES
-----------------------------
Kanodia, Gaurav
Punani, Rohit

SQL>
```

If input string's format differs, then the above (obviously) won't work properly.

---

**[EDIT**]

Here's one option how you might be doing that. I'm not very good at complex regular expressions so I wrote a function which will replace even comma occurrences with a `#`, and use that function later.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_rep (par_string in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    -- replace every second occurrence of a comma with a #
  5    l_cnt  number := regexp_count(par_string, ',');
  6    l_str  varchar2(100) := par_string;
  7  begin
  8    for i in 1 .. l_cnt loop
  9      if mod(i, 2) = 0 then
 10         l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, ',', '#', 1, (i/2)+1);
 11      end if;
 12    end loop;
 13    return l_str;
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

This query shows how to avoid *wrong* result if there are multiple rows.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Kanodia, Gaurav,Punani, Rohit,Singhal, Bhavya'            from dual union all
  3     select 'Little, Foot, MT0, DbFiddle'                              from dual union all
  4     select 'January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August' from dual)
  5  select
  6    col,
  7    trim(regexp_substr(f_rep(col), '[^#]+', 1, column_value)) repcol_split
  8  from test,
  9       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                           connect by level <= regexp_count(f_rep(col), '#') + 1
 11                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

COL                                                      REPCOL_SPLIT
-------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
Kanodia, Gaurav,Punani, Rohit,Singhal, Bhavya            Kanodia, Gaurav
Kanodia, Gaurav,Punani, Rohit,Singhal, Bhavya            Punani, Rohit
Kanodia, Gaurav,Punani, Rohit,Singhal, Bhavya            Singhal, Bhavya
Little, Foot, MT0, DbFiddle                              Little, Foot
Little, Foot, MT0, DbFiddle                              MT0, DbFiddle
January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August January, February
January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August March, April
January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August May, June
January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August July, August

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: What should I do in order to check the even occurence i.e. suppose there are three names lastname, firstname,lastname, firstname,lastname, firstname,lastname, firstname

Comment: You'd replace 2nd, 4th, 6th, ... occurrence of a comma with # and modify level value to number of commas divided by 2.

Comment: yes But how to do that? I tried but its not giving the resut

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f4d2defb1c21c6531496c985b51b061f) This does not work for more than 2 pairs and generates exponentially more duplicate rows if the input has more than one row.

Comment: Gaurav, I've edited my message, have a look. @MT0: yes, that's what I said. A new query fixes that.

Comment: You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '(.*?,.*?)(,|$)', 1, column_value, NULL, 1)` [db<.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7ef26704c63c98dd6b6f515039493a3e)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- for one row
with s as
(select 'Kanodia, Gaurav,Punani, Rohit' str from dual)
select regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+,[^,]+', 1, level) str
from s
connect by level <= ceil(regexp_count(str, ',') / 2);

STR
------------------------------
Kanodia, Gaurav
Punani, Rohit

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

-- for multiple rows
with s as
(select 1 id, 'Kanodia, Gaurav,Punani, Rohit' str from dual union all
 select 2 id, '1, 2, 3, 4' str from dual union all
 select 3 id, '6, 7, 8, 9' str from dual
)
select id, level num, regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+,[^,]+', 1, level) str
from s
connect by id = prior id and level <= ceil(regexp_count(str, ',') / 2)
and prior dbms_random.value is not null;

        ID        NUM STR
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         1          1 Kanodia, Gaurav
         1          2 Punani, Rohit
         2          1 1, 2
         2          2  3, 4
         3          1 6, 7
         3          2  8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not use regular expressions (only simple string functions) and will work for multiple input rows:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, col ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Kanodia, Gaurav,Punani, Rohit,Singhal, Bhavya' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Alice, Apple,Barry, Banana,Claire, Cherry' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```
WITH rsqfc ( id, col, string_start, string_end ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         col,
         1,
         INSTR( col, ',', 1, 2 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         col,
         string_end + 1,
         INSTR( col, ',', string_end + 1, 2 )
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  string_end > 0
)
SELECT id,
       CASE string_end
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( col, string_start )
       ELSE SUBSTR( col, string_start, string_end - string_start )
       END  AS pair
FROM   rsqfc;
```

**Output**:

```
ID | PAIR           
-: | :--------------
 1 | Kanodia, Gaurav
 2 | Alice, Apple   
 1 | Punani, Rohit  
 2 | Barry, Banana  
 1 | Singhal, Bhavya
 2 | Claire, Cherry
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eeeb5e74826dbcdb956e294ff408102d)*